# Build a List of Arrays recursively in Scala

Tags: scala

I am newbie to Scala and I am trying to build a list of arrays recursively in scala, here is the code I have, it is not throwing any error when I run it, but, its not printing anything when I try unCons.foreach(println)

```
val Tot = 5
val Num = 5

var unCons = ListBuffer[String]()

    for(j <- 1 to Tot)
      {
      var OurArr = ListBuffer[String]()

      for(i <- 1 to Num)
        {
          OurArr:+("true")
        }

      unCons:+(OurArr.toList)
 }
```

The result I am expecting is something like this

```
[[true, true, true, true, true],
[true, true, true, true, true],
[true, true, true, true, true],
[true, true, true, true, true],
[true, true, true, true, true]]
```

Any idea, where I am going wrong?

Comment: What's the result you're getting then?

Comment: nothing. unCons.foreach(println) does not print anything at all.

Comment: Ah. unCons is an ListBuffer of Strings but actually you're putting ListBuffer[Strings] inside.

Comment: I am converting the inner list buffer to list and then adding it to the unCons ListBuffer, is that wrong ?

Comment: unCons type is wrong. It's not an Array of Strings but an Array of Arrays of Strings (ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]]).

Comment: No luck, that didn't work either

Comment: Propably some other error that I'm missing then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea, where I am going wrong?

There are three errors you are making:

1. `unCons` is of type `ListBuffer[String]`. `OurArr` is also of type `ListBuffer[String]`. You are trying to add the collection `OurArr` to `unCons` which will give you a type mismatch error. `unCons` only accepts elements of a type `String` while you are trying to add elements of type `ListBuffer[String]` to it. So, first make your unCons of type ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]] so that it can accept elements of type `OurArr`
2. You are using the :+ method to append elements to your OurArr collection `OurArr:+("true")`, which returns a **new collection** instead of editing that collection in place.

   From the scaladoc:

> def +:(elem: A): ListBuffer[A]
>   A copy of the list buffer with an element prepended.

In your case, you should use  `OurArr += ("true")` which edits your collection in place and does not return a new collection.

You would guess that operations on mutable collections would return the same collection after operations. But that is NOT the case. Many operations on mutable collections return a new copy of the collection and you will need to capture that new collection.

3. This line: `unCons:+(OurArr.toList)` is causing the same issue as #2 above. The :+ operator is returning a new collection and you are not capturing that collection in a variable. Instead, you could use `unCons += OurArr` to edit the collection in place.

Last but not the least, you should AVOID VARS as far as possible in Scala. You will be surprised that you rarely ever need to use a `var` in Scala. For example, in your case: you used two vars:

```
var unCons = ListBuffer[String]()
var OurArr = ListBuffer[String]()
```

Both of them can be val's with no change on your code's behavior. Remember, when you declare an object as a val it does NOT mean you can'S change/edit the content of the object. THE only difference is that you can't change the pointer to point to some different memory address. So, in both your cases you can safely use vals:

So your code becomes:

```
val Tot = 5
val Num = 5

  val unCons = ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]]()

      for(j <- 1 to Tot)
        {
        val OurArr = ListBuffer[String]()

        for(i <- 1 to Num)
          {
            OurArr += ("true")
          }

       unCons += OurArr
   }
```

Comment: Samar, Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

The "Scala way" might be to use `List.fill`

```
scala> List.fill(5)(List.fill(5)(true))
res0: List[List[Boolean]] = List(List(true, true, true, true, true), List(true, true, true, true, true), List(true, true, true, true, true), List(true, true, true, true, true), List(true, true, true, true, true))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a number of issues going on.

First you're not properly assigning to the `ListBuffer`.

```
OurArr :+= "true"
```

Next you're `unCons` is the wrong type for what you're trying to do.

```
var unCons = ListBuffer[List[String]]()
```

After these fixes you'll want to look into good Scala practice, like avoiding the use of `var` whenever possible (and it is almost always possible).

One other thing: there's no recursion in this code.  If you're trying to build a list recursively (as the question title suggests) then you need a completely different approach.